# Test automation Google Apps Script Gmail Add-ons

Tags: google-apps-script, automation, integration-testing, gmail-addons

I am working on Gmail Add-on using Google Apps Script. I am using [Clasp](https://script.google.com) to develop it on locally then using this I am pushing it to [script.google.com](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/clasp).

In local, I can do **Unit testing** using any JavaScript testing framework.

But is there any way to do **Integration testing** and automate it?

Answer (score 0):

The official method for automating Google Apps Script is to use the [`run` command](https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/docs/run.md) of [claps](https://github.com/google/clasp). `clasp` is a command line tool that lets you develop Apps Script projects locally.